# How to search a list with user input?

Tags: python, list, indexing

So far I have...

```
    def main():
        list = [8, 25, 10, 99, 54, 3, 61, 24]
        print("Your list is: ",list)
        new = input("Please choose a number from the list:")
        print("Your numbers index is:", list.index(new))
        input("Press enter to close program")
```

So my issue is that I can't figure out how to take the user input and get the index of the users choice. For example, if the user entered 99, my program will return "Your numbers index is:3"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function returns a string, while your list contains ints. You need to convert the string to int:

```
new = int(input("Please choose a number from the list: "))
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. I keep getting a Syntax Error: invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked the following code.  Can you try running it?

```
def main():
    list = [8, 25, 10, 99, 54, 3, 61, 24]
    print("Your list is: ", list)
    new = int(input("Please choose a number from the list:"))
    print("Your numbers index is:", list.index(new))
    input("Press enter to close program")

main()
```

Comment: If one of the answers here helped you, consider upvoting or accepting those answers.  Otherwise answer with how you fixed it so other people can learn from this question